# Docker.service fails to start, error "failed to mount overlay: no such device" on Raspbian

Tags: docker, raspbian

I recently had a problem with my raspbian installation. Probably some upgrade messed up my SSD boot. After resolving it, I noticed that docker.service refuses to start. On the service's log it says

```
Apr 23 19:24:08 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Apr 23 19:24:08 raspberrypi dockerd[1629]: time="2020-04-23T19:24:08.702984211+01:00" level=info msg="Starting up"
Apr 23 19:24:08 raspberrypi dockerd[1629]: time="2020-04-23T19:24:08.706657044+01:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Apr 23 19:24:08 raspberrypi dockerd[1629]: time="2020-04-23T19:24:08.707181266+01:00" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Apr 23 19:24:08 raspberrypi dockerd[1629]: time="2020-04-23T19:24:08.707520970+01:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <
Apr 23 19:24:08 raspberrypi dockerd[1629]: time="2020-04-23T19:24:08.707855840+01:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Apr 23 19:24:08 raspberrypi dockerd[1629]: time="2020-04-23T19:24:08.711273840+01:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Apr 23 19:24:08 raspberrypi dockerd[1629]: time="2020-04-23T19:24:08.711450507+01:00" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Apr 23 19:24:08 raspberrypi dockerd[1629]: time="2020-04-23T19:24:08.711545396+01:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <
Apr 23 19:24:08 raspberrypi dockerd[1629]: time="2020-04-23T19:24:08.711626674+01:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Apr 23 19:24:08 raspberrypi dockerd[1629]: time="2020-04-23T19:24:08.721460748+01:00" level=error msg="failed to mount overlay: no such device" storage-driver=overlay2
Apr 23 19:24:08 raspberrypi dockerd[1629]: time="2020-04-23T19:24:08.721569822+01:00" level=error msg="[graphdriver] prior storage driver overlay2 failed: driver not supported"
Apr 23 19:24:08 raspberrypi dockerd[1629]: failed to start daemon: error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported
Apr 23 19:24:08 raspberrypi systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 23 19:24:08 raspberrypi systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 23 19:24:08 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

I wasn't able to find anything relevant online. Ideally I would like to avoid losing my docker images

Edit: The kernel version was 4.19.114-v7l+, however there were no modules installed for this kernel under /lib/module. Running a "sudo apt install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel" fixed it.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate for https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/. Some diagnostics to include in your question: What kernel version are you running (`uname -r`)? Is there a directory matching your kernel version in `/lib/modules`? What happens when you try to run `modprobe overlay`?

Comment: The kernel version is 4.19.114-v7l+
There is no directory matching this version no (!)
Running modprobe returns with
`
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.19.114-v7l+/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module overlay not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.114-v7l+
`

Comment: no wonder wh it can't find the module!

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right track. But you'll still want to post the question elsewhere, since it's off topic here on Stack Overflow, and include that information in the question itself.

Comment: no that was it. I completely overlooked it and didn't check it. Now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You might have made a kernel update and need to reboot in order to use the new kernel instead of the old one.

Answer (score 3):

In case you have an old kernel, update the kernel.

Check if modules are installed for the kernel under /lib/module.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel
```

should fix it.

I had the same problem in a VM on a **Xen host**, and fixed it by installing pygrub and its own kernel inside the VM: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71763164/1069083

Answer (score 1):

Your kernel might not support `overlayl2`:

1. Try to upgrade your kernel (check if it has support for `overlay2`)
2. Or use another driver like `aufs` or `devicemapper` for Debian > 9, and `overlay` for Ubuntu.

NB.: `devicemapper` is tagged as deprecated for Docker.

https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/

After your changes, you also might have to remove `/var/lib/docker` before restarting the service.

Good luck !

Comment: Must note that you will lost all docker data (images, volumes) when remove `/var/lib/docker`