# overlay2 driver not supported

Tags: docker, docker-in-docker

I am running a GitHub agent inside AKS cluster with Docker installed. I can run it successfully with VFS storage driver, however I want to use Overlay 2 because it's faster.
I get the following message:

```
sudo dockerd &
...
INFO[2021-06-12T22:38:41.674415376Z] containerd successfully booted in 0.029163s
INFO[2021-06-12T22:38:41.692284696Z] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2021-06-12T22:38:41.692316597Z] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2021-06-12T22:38:41.692340397Z] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2021-06-12T22:38:41.692352097Z] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2021-06-12T22:38:41.693462211Z] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2021-06-12T22:38:41.693484611Z] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2021-06-12T22:38:41.693505611Z] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2021-06-12T22:38:41.693519612Z] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
ERRO[2021-06-12T22:38:41.702131518Z] failed to mount overlay: invalid argument     storage-driver=overlay2
INFO[2021-06-12T22:38:41.702558423Z] stopping event stream following graceful shutdown  error="context canceled" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
INFO[2021-06-12T22:38:41.702674724Z] stopping healthcheck following graceful shutdown  module=libcontainerd
failed to start daemon: error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported
```

My /etc/docker/daemon.json settings:

```
{
  "storage-driver": "overlay2",
  "storage-opts": [
    "overlay2.override_kernel_check=true"
  ]
}
```

Filesystem types:

```
Filesystem     Type     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay        overlay   49G   20G   29G  41% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1      ext4      49G   20G   29G  41% /etc/hosts
shm            tmpfs     64M  8.0K   64M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs    3.9G   12K  3.9G   1% /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
```

Kernel version: 5.4.0-1046-azure

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
overlay        overlay   49G   20G   29G  41% /
```

From the filesystem, it looks like you are running within a container. With Docker-in-Docker, typically you'll have a volume mounted at /var/lib/docker to get the docker filesystems off of container's overlay filesystem because you can't do overlay on top of overlay. The [docs on storage driver backing filesystems](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/#supported-backing-filesystems) shows the supported underlying filesystems for each storage driver.

If you can't implement a volume mount for docker, then you're limited to vfs which works everywhere but is very disk intensive (the entire filesystem is copied for each layer), or fuse-overlayfs which is typically used for rootless installs and may not be available for your use case.

Comment: The thing is, that since we're using AKS 1.20.5 cluster, the default container runtime is Containerd, not Docker, so there is no /var/lib/docker to mount from.

Comment: I managed to get it working, by mounting a /var/lib/docker, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are inside a VM on a Xen host, you need to activate pygrub for the VM and install its own kernel inside the VM (instead of using the kernel of the host)

see: https://wiki.debian.org/PyGrub

1. inside the VM:

```
mkdir /boot/grub
apt-get install -y linux-image-amd64
cat > /boot/grub/menu.lst << EOF

default         0
timeout         2

title           Debian GNU/Linux
root            (hd0,0)
kernel          /vmlinuz root=/dev/xvda2 ro
initrd          /initrd.img

title           Debian GNU/Linux (recovery mode)
root            (hd0,0)
kernel          /vmlinuz root=/dev/xvda2 ro single
initrd          /initrd.img

EOF
```

2. comment out

```
#kernel      = '/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-20-amd64'
#extra       = 'elevator=noop'
#ramdisk     = '/boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-20-amd64'
```

and add:

```
bootloader = 'pygrub'
```

3. restart the VM

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.docker.com/engine/deprecated/#support-for-the-overlay2override_kernel_check-storage-option

Support for the overlay2.override_kernel_check storage option
Deprecated in Release: v19.03 Removed in Release: v24.0