# Failed to mount overlay: no such device storage-driver=overlay2

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I try install docker-ce on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa) and I have error with overlay2. According [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/), it will be works since I have kernel 4.4.182-mainline-rev1.

```
INFO[2021-11-03T15:02:55.375424503+01:00] Starting up                                  
INFO[2021-11-03T15:02:55.376873274+01:00] detected 127.0.0.53 nameserver, assuming systemd-resolved, so using resolv.conf: /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf 
INFO[2021-11-03T15:02:55.380156220+01:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2021-11-03T15:02:55.380343883+01:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2021-11-03T15:02:55.380511607+01:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2021-11-03T15:02:55.380746348+01:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2021-11-03T15:02:55.386164293+01:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2021-11-03T15:02:55.386390699+01:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2021-11-03T15:02:55.386507127+01:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2021-11-03T15:02:55.386582789+01:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
ERRO[2021-11-03T15:02:55.393126880+01:00] failed to mount overlay: no such device       storage-driver=overlay2
failed to start daemon: error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported
```

I deleted `/var/lib/docker`.

I created /etc/docker/daemon.json with:

```
{
 "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
```

I added `DOCKER_OPTS="-s overlay2"`
to `/etc/default/docker`.

Nothing works. Please help.

Comment: I'm having exact same issue on a pi.

Comment: I had the same issue in a debian VM inside a Xen host, solved it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71763164/1069083

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75579116/12555857