# Docker installation issue : Failed to mount overlay: no such device storage-driver=overlay2

Tags: docker, ubuntu, filesystems, overlay, docker-ce

I am trying to install docker on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. I installing from *.deb packages. While installing docker, it runs into the following error.

```
Failed to mount overlay: no such device storage-driver=overlay2
```

I created

```
{
  "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
```

as per https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/ but that did not help either.

Edit 1:

`lsmod | grep overlay` returns empty.

`sudo modprobe overlay' returns fatal error. In fact, there are no module files under` /lib/modules/' for the 'uname -a' version of the kernel.

Comment: What's the result of `lsmod | grep overlay`? If the return is empty, try `sudo modprobe overlay` and then try to start docker. If this fixes the issue, you will then have to find out why this kernel module is not loaded by default when it should be. The most obvious is to look if it is not blacklisted in some file under `/etc/modprobe.d/*.conf`. Note: if the module is loaded by default, please do not reply in comments: edit your question.

Comment: `lsmod | grep overlay` returns empty.

`sudo modprobe overlay' returns fatal error. In fact, there are no module files under `/lib/modules/' for the 'uname -a' version of the kernel.

Comment: Do you have a `linux-modules-$(uname -r)` package installed? It holds the overlay module which should be present in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/fs/overlayfs/overlay.ko`

Comment: If this was an upgrade, based on [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/1028682/iptables-kernel-module-missing-after-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-20-04), I suggest you run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-modules-$(uname -r)` to see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: It does not have `linux-modules-$(uname -r)` installed. I can't do `linux-modules-$(uname -r)` because this is a VM isolated from internet (although I can transfer data via other means into.) Are there any linux-module installation files from which we can install `/lib/module` files? I have been looking without success.

Comment: For example on [this apt mirror](http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/)

Answer (score 13):

for me the error was thrown when trying to start the `docker.service`, I found out that it was because I have upgraded the kernel and not yet rebooted the system, *modprobe* will fail with no error message, because the path `/usr/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/` no longer exists.

I rebooted the system and the service starts normally again.