# Airflow docker-compose from another docker container on Azure Machine Learning Compute Cluster

Tags: python, azure, docker, docker-compose, airflow

I’m attempting to run Airflow in docker with docker-compose from inside another container. This container is created by default by an Azure Machine Learning compute cluster that I want to use to run my Airflow DAG.

The problem is that I have the following error when I try to execute `docker-compose build` through the ScriptRunConfig class (see script below).

```
error creating aufs mount to /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/3d54c61133023e1d3700ce9746529dc8328e739346d4123d632951f11acdf122-init: mount target=/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/3d54c61133023e1d3700ce9746529dc8328e739346d4123d632951f11acdf122-init data=br:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/3d54c61133023e1d3700ce9746529dc8328e739346d4123d632951f11acdf122-init=rw:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/d6e643e28d8729f8972b78bedd2de1de602879b65ff56e07e76a236d3096b709=ro+wh:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/8d3dde63564e16508dbf64e7baae79a6b2913b3262cb6dba7027e1fdf8bb6f8f=ro+wh:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/fa2e9c9ac8ff7af5f5d35e4d2081fac4bb5139d760675e9608d2b8d04f096837=ro+wh:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/d34747b3a1646124aa7a7a0fed4790e1264667aa58fc4de2288a10e4b68673ce=ro+wh:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/ea46ddfc022eb268aa428376132bc52b00b317e747d63078a38d044bae5d48ec=ro+wh:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/b3c155d801b49d8252a3926493328d471c8f4cfd72c553771374e3952a999d95=ro+wh:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/a067d04104f7a70c6194a3e742be72fc221759b18628285e7fd16a2d678120f3=ro+wh:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/3db994298571c09ee3d40abf21f657f9c8650a6fe0ea2c6c6c7590eb7c6c712f=ro+wh:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/273fc331f9ebae1d0a01963d46bf9edca6d91a089d4791066cb170954eb7609c=ro+wh:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/419a894bbee2b9b8ec05deed26dcfc21f234276e06d765d03ed939b918d3908f=ro+wh:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/e91d472c4e53f2a2eae97aca59f7dcacdf57a4b22d64991c348528e4081500d6=ro+wh:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/c23cc64e903b5254c19446e8ddc6db0253cbd19e239860c1dc95440ca65aae94=ro+wh:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/5794fefdefed444bf17de20f6c3ecf93743cccef83169c94aba62ec902c8380f=ro+wh,dio,xino=/dev/shm/aufs.xino: invalid argument
```

What I tried so far:

1. **Discarded option** : Using a `docker:dind` custom image where I installed *curl* and *docker-compose*. The problem is that **it fails when building the image** because:

   - it seems that Azure Machine Learning adds other steps to the Dockerfile to setup the conda environment needed for my project … but conda is not installed by default in the docker:dind image.
   - The Official docker image is based on Alpine Linux but Azure Machine Learning is only compatible with systems specifications including Ubuntu, Conda … as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-train-with-custom-image#use-a-custom-dockerfile-optional)
2. **The option presented in this question**: Using an image already available to Azure Machine Learning where I installed the *Docker engine* and *docker-compose*. **The image is built successfully but I get the error shown above during the execution of my script by the compute cluster**

Here's the Dockerfile for the custom Image (ubuntu os) used by the compute cluster to setup the environment. It is referred to as *Dockerfile_cluster* in the python script below.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi3.1.2-ubuntu18.04:20211029.v1

USER root

# install docker
RUN apt-get update -y \
 && apt-get install -y \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg \
    lsb-release \
 && mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings \
 && curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg \
 && echo \
  "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null \
 && apt-get update -y \
 && apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

# install docker-compose
RUN curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

And my docker-compose.yml file (Different dockerfile than the first one) :

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
      - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
    ports:
      - "5434:5432"
  init_db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: bash -c "airflow db init && airflow db upgrade"
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  scheduler:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    command:  bash -c "airflow scheduler"
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "8080:8793"
    volumes:
      - ./airflow_dags:/opt/airflow/dags
      - ./data:/opt/airflow/data
      - ./.git:/opt/airflow/.git
      - ./conf:/opt/airflow/conf
      - ./airflow_logs:/opt/airflow/logs
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
  webserver:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    hostname: webserver
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    command: bash -c "airflow users create -r Admin -u admin -e admin@example.com -f admin -l user -p admin && airflow webserver"
    volumes:
      - ./airflow_dags:/opt/airflow/dags
      - ./data:/opt/airflow/data
      - ./.git:/opt/airflow/.git
      - ./conf:/opt/airflow/conf
      - ./airflow_logs:/opt/airflow/logs
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - "5000:8080"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 32
```

And finally the script I use to submit my experiment to the compute cluster.

```
from azureml.core import Workspace, Experiment, Environment, ScriptRunConfig
from azureml.core.authentication import ServicePrincipalAuthentication

# Create an environment from conda reqs
env = Environment.from_conda_specification(name = "env_name", file_path = "./src/conda.yml")              

# Use custom image from Dockerfile
env.docker.base_image = None
env.docker.base_dockerfile = "./Dockerfile_cluster"


# Instantiate ServicePrincipalAuth object
svc_pr = ServicePrincipalAuthentication(tenant_id=tenant_id,
       service_principal_id=sp_id,
       service_principal_password=sp_pwd)

# Instantiate AML Workspace object
ws = Workspace(
       subscription_id=sub_id,
       resource_group=rg_name,
       workspace_name=ws_name,
       auth=svc_pr
       )

command ="bash -c 'service docker start && docker-compose build --no-cache'".split()
experiment = Experiment(workspace=ws, name='exp-test')

config = ScriptRunConfig(source_directory='.', command = command, compute_target='cpt-cluster', environment=env)
# Submit experiment

run = experiment.submit(config)
aml_url = run.get_portal_url()
print(aml_url)
run.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)
```

In the script above, I only tried to build first before running the services.

Normally, the commands I use to run my Airflow DAG locally or using a compute instance are:

1. `docker-compose build –no-cache`
2. `docker-compose up postgres`

In another terminal:

3. `docker-compose up init_db`
4. `docker-compose up scheduler webserver`

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What do you get as the output of the storage driver running `docker info` command with `ScriptRunConfig`? Try make the storage driver used by the docker daemon running in the container the same as that for the daemon running in Compute.

Comment: Here's what I get for the storage driver used by the daemon running in compute : 
`Storage Driver: overlay2`

And for the storage driver in  the container :

`Storage Driver: aufs`.

Which one should I change and how ?  Thanks

Comment: Change the one for the docker daemon running in the container to overlay2. https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#configure-docker-with-the-overlay-or-overlay2-storage-driver

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. The docker engine simply does not restart after I create the daemon.json file with {"storage-driver": "overlay2"}. 
Following the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/#supported-backing-filesystems), it seems that only `xfs` and `ext4` are supported for `overlay2` storage driver.
There are also two SO questions about that : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67953609/overlay2-driver-not-supported) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70631927/using-overlay2-storage-driver-with-an-overlay-filesystem).

Comment: I don't know if it is relevant, but docker inside the docker container does not start automatically on boot. So, I need to execute `service docker start` before I can do `docker info` etc....